# Error Message When Web Browser Don't Have Support Of Scripting

Tags: javascript, scripting, browser

I'm developing a site that I know because of the site theme that it will be accessed on mobile devices and Internet Explorer For Windows CE 1, 1,1 and 2 don't have support for the `<script>` tag(as you can see on [this table](http://www.hpcfactor.com/support/cesd/d/0001.asp)). Then I want to build a way that when the user have a browser that don't have a browser with scripting support it will show a message like:

```
<center><b>You don't have a browser with scripting support, then you can't see the content of the page</b></center>
```

How I can do this without?

PS: If you see the table on the link it says that the `<noscript>` tag isn't supported by the same browsers that don't support `<script>` tag.

Comment: I didn't read that link closely, removed my answer.

Comment: Ok, but undelete it and turn it into a cw, then other people can be helped by your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you see the table on the link it says that the `<noscript>` tag isn't supported by the same browsers that don't support `<script>` tag.

Yes, that's the whole idea. If a browser doesn't support scripting, and doesn't support noscript, it will ignore the unrecognized noscript tag and just show the *contents* of the noscript element.

For browsers that don't support noscript, it would be like having `<foo>hello</foo>`. Browsers would ignore the foo tag and show "hello".

Modern browsers support the `<noscript>` tag by ignoring the whole element and its contents.